# Filter data for last 24 hours using c#?

Tags: c#

Here i am calculating the server restart count.

i need the server restart count for last 24 hours.

```
string logType = "System";
EventLog ev = new EventLog(logType, System.Environment.MachineName);    
int count=0;
for (int i = ev.Entries.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
EventLogEntry CurrentEntry = ev.Entries[i];
if (CurrentEntry.Source.ToUpper() == "USER32")
{
count = count + 1;
}
}
ev.Close();
```

and i have tried like

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan ts = dt.Subtract(CurrentEntry.TimeGenerated);
int hours = (ts.Days * 24) + ts.Hours;
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: By the way, `TimeSpan` has `TotalHours` property

Comment: edited my answer to provide an improved solution giving best of both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var ev = new EventLog("system", System.Environment.MachineName);
var count = ev.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>()
    .Where (e => e.TimeGenerated >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) 
        && e.Source.Equals("USER32", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).Count();
```

**Edit:**

Considering jCoder's comment about the enteries being sorted on TimeGenerated. Using this code will gain performance:

```
var ev = new EventLog("system", System.Environment.MachineName);
int count = 0;
var y = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
for (int i = ev.Entries.Count - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    if(ev.Entries[i].TimeGenerated < y)
        break;
    if(ev.Entries[i].Source.Equals("USER32", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        count++;
}
```

Comment: Quite a readable solutions, although it might enumerate all event log entries because it has no "knowledge" about the order of the entries (latest entries might be last in the collection).

Comment: @jCoder Thats a good point. If the Entries collection is sorted on TimeGenerated. Starting from the end and stop when not in timespan anymore might speed things up.

Comment: @jCoder, Magnus. I'm dubios that sorting would yield a saving, however if we always knew the default order ...

Comment: @Jodrell by "sorted" I meant deafult ordered

Comment: @Magnus, Jodrell It was just some observation when playing around with LINQ to get the entries. However, I'm not 100% sure too, if the entries are always in the "correct" order. (Maybe loop back 25 hours and only count entries back 24 hours to make sure not to skip few entries in the wrong order at the 24-hour-point. Just a guess though.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `CurrentEntry.TimeGenerated` to check when it has happened.

put one more condition at `if (CurrentEntry.Source.ToUpper() == "USER32")` to check if TimeGenerated is in last 24 hours

Answer (score 1):

This code will give you the count of events, in tha last day, that have a source of `USER32` in the System event log.

```
int count; //your result  

//When yesterday became today
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0));  

using (EventLog appLog = new EventLog("System"))
{
    count = appLog.Entries.OfType<EventLogEntry>().Where(
        e => (e.Source.ToUpperInvariant == "USER32") && 
             (e.TimeGenerated > yesterday)).Count();
}
```

**EDIT: Or Even better, taking good bits from Mangus's answer**

```
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
int count = 0;

using (Eventlog appLog = new EventLog("System"))
{
    count = appLog.Entries.OfType<EventLogEntry>().Count(
        e.Source.Equals("USER32", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && 
        e.TimeGenerated > yesterday
    )

}
```

If "USER32" events do not have a direct correllation with system restart events, this will not give you a count of system restarts.